# How to link Eigen and BLIS

Tags: eigen, blas

I looked that [Eigen can use with BLAS](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicUsingBlasLapack.html).
And [BLIS](http://github.com/flame/blis) is the BLAS-like dense linear algebra libraries.
Can Eigen link BLIS?  How to do it?
THX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply link to the BLAS compatibility layer of BLIS using the instructions you referenced: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicUsingBlasLapack.html, that is compile your application with `-DEIGEN_USE_BLAS -lblis`